# Spring Tool Suite - Setting up Database Connection to MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to create a new connection profile from within the Database Development perspective in Spring Tool Suite version 3.7.0. I need to connect to SQL Server 2012. In the dialog box where I need to specify the driver and connection details, I do not have an option of adding a driver jar and connection URL for MS Sql server 2012. The list goes only upto sql server 2008. Any thoughts on how I could connect to sql server 2012?

Thanks!

Comment: you also using Maven build-tool? could add it as a dependency if so

Comment: I believe to set up the connection profile, STS does not use the maven build tool. It only asks you to specify where the driver jars are located. Once specified (I chose the sql server 2008 option, and specified sqljdbc4.jar for the driver jar file and the connection URL pointing to a sql server 2012 DB). I was hoping it would accept the above and allow me to test the connection, but that option was grayed out. So, it's not recognizing the 2012 connection settings.

Comment: as this feature of STS is coming from the general Eclipse JEE package distribution, it might be useful to add additional tags for Eclipse and Eclipse Data Tools - or ask their forums at Eclipse.